# Obtaing supported GPUs on Cocos2d-x

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to obtain which GPU is supported in the device which runs the game in order to use the correct texture compression for that GPU (I don't know if this is the best way to do this, i'm open to any suggestion :) )

```
std::string GPUInfo::getTC()
{
    std::string TC;
    cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->gatherGPUInfo();
    if(cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->supportsPVRTC())
        TC = ".pvr.ccz";
    else if(cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->supportsATITC())
        TC = ".dds";
    else
        TC = ".png";
    CCLOG("Texture compression format -> %s", TC.c_str());
    return TC;
}
```

But this keeps causing this error:

**call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)**

Is there another way to obtain which GPUs are supported in the current device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

```
cocos2d::Configuration::getInstance()->gatherGPUInfo();
```

You don't need to call gatherGPUInfo() because it was automatically called from Director::setOpenGLView.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/fe4b34fcc3b6bb312bd66ca5b520630651575bc3/cocos/base/CCDirector.cpp#L361-L369

You can call supportsPVRTC() and supportsATITC() without GL error from anywhere in the main thread, but you should call it after Cocos2d-x initialization (setOpenGLView).